# Install of QGIS3.0 on Mac OSX using KyngChaos prebuilt binaries

Tags: qgis, osx, python-3

The installer doesn't work because it requires Python 3.6 to be installed as a framework in **/Library/Frameworks** (or so I believe). It is insufficient to have Python 3.6 installed by **Macports** (in **/opt/local/Library/Frameworks**). I don't know about **Homebrew**. I am not sanguine about trying to install Python into **/Library/Frameworks**. It is not clear where a binary from python.org does install, and whether it messes us links elsewhere in the directory structure. Does anyone have information about this? Why is the build from KyngChaos so inflexible?

Comment: See [QGIS 3 Must use python.org Python 3](http://www.kyngchaos.com/blog/2018/20180315_qgis_3_must_use_python.org_python_3) or If you use MacPorts use the QGIS version of MacPorts

Comment: I plucked up courage, and installed the python3.6 download, python-3.6.5-macosx10.9.pkg. It installs into /Library/Frameworks and not, as I had feared, into /System/Library/Frameworks. Further, the python executable is named python3, as are the utilities commonly used (pip3, idle3..). I then was able to install the GDAL frameworks and the QGIS frameworks from KyngChaos. So afaik everything installed ok and not clobbering of the system python occurred. (But I now have no fewer than 4 pythons installed 27 and 36 from macports, 27 from the system, and this last 36)